# what is the condition on coefficients of a polynomial to converge to zero uniformly on real line?

Tags: limits

Let {bn} and {cn} be sequences of real numbers. Then what is the necessary and sufficient condition for sequence of polynomial bn(x) +cn(x^2) to converge to zero on real line uniformly?

Comment: the general theorem is that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x) = \infty$ then $f_n$ cannot converge to $0$ (or any bounded function) uniformly on $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (but it can converge uniformly on $x\in [A,B]$, for any fixed $A,B$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the polynomials to converge **uniformly**, the series $b_n$ and $c_n$ must be constant zero after a certain $n_0$, as every non-constant polynomial is unbounded. If you want them to converge pointwise, then you can probably do with less stringent conditions.

Comment: Thanks. What would be condition for pointwise convergence?

Comment: I'd say you would need the sequences to decrease pretty fast. Probably $b_n$ decreasing strictly faster than linearly and $c_n$ strictly faster than quadratically.

Answer (score 1):

$b_n$ and $c_n$ must vanish for sufficiently large $n$ since every nonconstant polynomial is unbounded.

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? Reason?